# Displaying products on PDT.php page

Tags: php, variables, paypal, paypal-sandbox, eclipse-pdt

In sandbox mode all products bought is displayed with no problem. When testing im also sent to the pdt.php with the url ending with item_name=54 for example. When in live mode i get to same pdt.php but the url is ending with item_name= without a number and of course there is the problem. But why? Both the sandbox button (buy now) and the live button (add to cart) have the same id=54.

Before payment is done you get an overview of the products in the cart and here it also differs a bit. In sandbox mode the product is listed as Objektsnummer:54 ss here: http://snag.gy/0SmI6.jpg but in live mode the product is listed as Artikelnummer54 ss here: http://snag.gy/ZSIH4.jpg

So basically article number and object number but in Swedish.

Why is this? Is the live using some other variable than item_name? I cannot find any other id-holder than item_name and its obviously not working on the live side.

Any help is really apprciated, I am stuk at the moment since it "should" work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with the language set on one of the accounts, or the language encoding you have set.  Check these settings on both accounts and make sure they are the same.